# Alert when color changes_Code in Pine Script on Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I want to get alert on tradingview when color changes to green, it pop-up an alert "Buy" and when color changes to orange it goes with alert "Sell".

But the script keeps showing up "Script could not be translated from: , title="Buy",  message="green buy")"
Please help me!

```
Study("Impulse MACD]", shorttitle="IMACD_LB", overlay=false)
lengthMA = input(34)
lengthSignal = input(9)
calc_smma(src, len) =>
    smma=na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    smma

calc_zlema(src, length) =>
    ema1=ema(src, length)
    ema2=ema(ema1, length)
    d=ema1-ema2
    ema1+d

src=hlc3
hi=calc_smma(high, lengthMA)
lo=calc_smma(low, lengthMA)
mi=calc_zlema(src, lengthMA) 

md=(mi>hi)? (mi-hi) : (mi<lo) ? (mi - lo) : 0
sb=sma(md, lengthSignal)
sh=md-sb
mdc=src>mi?src>hi?lime:green:src<lo?red:orange
plot(0, color=gray, linewidth=1, title="MidLine")
plot(md, color=mdc, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACD", style=histogram)
plot(sh, color=blue, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseHisto", style=histogram)
plot(sb, color=maroon, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACDCDSignal")

ebc=input(false, title="Enable bar colors")
barcolor(ebc?mdc:na)

*alertcondition(src>mi?src>hi?lime:green , title="Buy",  message="green buy")
alertcondition(src<lo?red:orange , title="Sell", message="red sell")
```

I tried to add the alertcondition but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the version declaration. Add `//@version=2' at the top of your script and also` study` should start with lower-case, so fix that too.

Coming to your question, `alertcondition()` expects a condition to throw the alert. You are passing `src>mi?src>hi?lime:green` to its `condition` argument however, this is just a color definitinon.

You should check if the previous color was not green and if the current bar is green. Wrtie that into a variable and use that variable to fire your alerts.

Example:

```
is_new_green = (mdc[1] != green) and (mdc == green)
alertcondition(is_new_green, "New green")
```

Comment: Sorry I do not have deep knowledge about coding. I tried below code but it didn't signal when the histogram changes color. Please help me. 

is_new_green = (mdc[1] != green) and (mdc == red)
alertcondition(is_new_green, "New green")
is_new_red = (mdc[1] != orange) and (mdc == lime)
alertcondition(is_new_green, "New red")

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have the correct code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mi script")
plot(close)

lengthMA = input(34)
lengthSignal = input(9)

calc_smma(src, len) =>
    smma = 0.0 // initialize smma with 0.0
    sma_val = ta.sma(src, len)
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma_val : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    smma

calc_zlema(src, length) =>
    ema1 = ta.ema(src, length)
    ema2 = ta.ema(ema1, length)
    d = ema1 - ema2
    ema1 + d

src = hlc3
smma = 0.0 // initialize smma with 0.0
hi = calc_smma(high, lengthMA)
lo = calc_smma(low, lengthMA)
mi = calc_zlema(src, lengthMA) 

md = (mi > hi) ? (mi - hi) : (mi < lo) ? (mi - lo) : 0
sb = calc_smma(md, lengthSignal)
sh = md - sb
mdc = src > mi ? src > hi ? color.lime : color.green : src < lo ? color.red : color.orange

plot(0, color=color.gray, linewidth=1, title="MidLine")
plot(md, color=mdc, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACD", style=plot.style_histogram)
plot(sh, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseHisto", style=plot.style_histogram)
plot(sb, color=color.maroon, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACDCDSignal")

ebc = input(false, title="Enable bar colors")
barcolor(ebc ? mdc : na)

buy_condition = src > mi and src > hi
sell_condition = src < lo

alertcondition(buy_condition, title="Buy", message="Green buy")
alertcondition(sell_condition, title="Sell", message="Red sell")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But It has 2 problems: 1) It works when the bar turns green but didn't work for the orange bar. 2) It gives false signal when the bar keeps on/off with green and red. Would it be possible to fire the alert when the bar is done? And 1 more thing, it shows only 2 parallel straight lines, not histogram, how can I fix it?

Comment: let me know your thought about this one:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).